# Why is console.log logging twice in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I have started learning React and I am not able to understand why is the console.log logging twice. Below is my code and when I inspect it in chrome it shows the word 'random-text' twice instead of once.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0

  };



  render() {
    console.log('random-text');

    return (
      <div>
        <span className={this.getBaadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button
          onClick={this.handleIncrement}
          className="btn btn-success m-2"
        >
          Increment
        </button>

        {/* <ul>
          {this.state.tags.map((tag) => (
            <li key={tag}>{tag}</li>
          ))}
        </ul> */}
      </div>
    );
  }

  getBaadgeClasses() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
  }

  formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }

  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})
  }

}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: I believe it's happening because you are calling getBaadgeClasses inside the render method, causing the component to re-render.
Try removing this call and see what you get.

Comment: `render` method is in react's lifecycle. it'll be triggered when your component's props or state changed.

Comment: @DavidG I tried removing the getBadgeClasses inside the render method but it still logged twice.. Infact even with an empty div in render it logged twice....

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The render function is a lifecycle function, called during the "render phase"

[image]

[react lifecycle methods diagram](https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/)

Notice that these functions are pure functions, and can be paused, aborted, or restarted by React. This means react can call render almost any number of times to reconcile the virtualDOM with the actual DOM.

[Detecting unexpected side effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it
>   can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic.
>   This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component `constructor`, ***`render`***, and `shouldComponentUpdate` methods
> - Class component static `getDerivedStateFromProps` method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument to `setState`)
> - Functions passed to `useState`, `useMemo`, or `useReducer`
>
> > **Note:**
> >
> > This only applies to development mode. Lifecycles will not be
> >     double-invoked in production mode.

If you truly want a one-to-one console log when the component updates use one of the other lifecycle functions, like `componentDidUpdate` to do the side-effect of logging details.

```
class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("random-text");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className={this.getBaadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button onClick={this.handleIncrement} className="btn btn-success m-2">
          Increment
        </button>

        {/* <ul>
          {this.state.tags.map((tag) => (
            <li key={tag}>{tag}</li>
          ))}
        </ul> */}
      </div>
    );
  }

  getBaadgeClasses() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
  }

  formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }

  handleIncrement = () => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };
}
```

[image: Edit use lifecycle function to log]

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. My doubt is will the react re-render even if there is no change in the state and props? Even with an empty div, the react is logging it twice. Why is this happening? I am a beginner so please excuse if the doubt sounds silly.

Comment: @HBK8396 I believe you are conflating the react framework invoking the render function (to compute a diff) with it committing anything to the DOM. Read the description of the "commit phase": "Can work with DOM, *run side effects*, schedule updates" and look at the lifecycle functions where you can do this. React traverses the entire virtualDOM tree and invokes `render` on every component, *then* it compares the output, *then* commits the diff. Even a component that renders static output (or `null` even) will have its render function invoked during reconciliation.

Comment: I understand it now sir. Everything is quite clear  and thank you very much.

Comment: This answer is good, for more information this would help: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Answer (score 32):

When you create this project, this project enables **Strict Mode** automatically. So, To solve this problem firstly open `index.js` file in your project and then disable strict mode.

Step 1: when you open `index.js` file then you will see something like this,

```js
root.render(
   <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
   </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Step2:
Now do this,

```js
root.render(
  // <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  // </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I hope this will help you. Thank You

Comment: Don't turn off strict mode. Strict Mode calls some of your functions twice in development for good reasons: https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-double-rendering-in-development

Answer (score 14):

The React team is no longer silencing console methods during the double render in Strict Mode. If you do not want to remove Strict Mode, like @Florian Motteau mentions, then you can go into React Dev Tools and check the box Hide logs during second render in Strict Mode. See screenshot below:

[image]

Here is the quote from the React Team, as well as the [link to the discussion](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/96) on their Github page.

> In Strict Mode, React double invokes render methods in order to flush out potential side effects. During the second render, React used to automatically silence console methods (ex. console.log() and console.warn()) to reduce the noise of multiple repeat logs. However, this ended up causing a lot of confusion for developers during debugging, so we are changing this behavior. - React Team