# SetTimeout in component executing twice in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When I render the App component the code inside setTimeout runs twice.

I saw that setTimeout runs after the call stack has finished executing. I don't know whether its relevant to this.

Is it something to do with how react renders components.

index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`Logged!`);
  },
  1000
  )
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Should `setTimeout` only run of `componentDidMount`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65766356/1927991

Answer (score 2):

Your `setTimeOut` is called on every render of the `App` component.

In your case, `React.StrictMode` causes the re-renders.

To prevent this, you can add it in a `useEffect` [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) with an empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`Logged!`);
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, []);
```

Comment: His component only renders once. https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-dhawan-iyv1t?file=/src/App.js Can you explain why the `setTimout` callback is triggered twice?

Comment: @codemonkey Because of the `StrictMode` I guess. Two `console.log('Logged!")` with it, one without it.

Comment: Yep! You should put that in your answer, because that's what the OP wants to know.