# button onClick firing twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component, stenciljs

```
  @State() open: boolean = false;

...
...
  private toggleSelect(source: string) {
    console.log('fired ' + source);
    this.open = !this.open;
    console.log('toggleSelect: Open is now ' + this.open);
    this.toggle.emit({ visible: this.open });
  }

  private handleSelect(value: string | undefined) {
    this.value = value;
    console.log('EMITTING ' + this.value);
    this.changeValue.emit(this.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Host>
        <button
          class={`select ${this.open ? 'icon-open' : 'icon-closed'} ${
            this.open ? 'select-open' : 'select-closed'
          }`}
          onClick={() => this.toggleSelect('button')}
        >
          <a> {this.getClosedDisplayValue(this.value)} </a>
          <div class={`select-panel ${this.open ? 'open' : 'close'}`}>
            {[{ value: 'undefined', name: '' }, ...this.data].map((item) => {
              {
                return (
                  <label class="checkmark" htmlFor={item.value}>
                    {this.getDisplayValue(item.value)}
                    <input
                      id={item.value}
                      title={this.getDisplayValue(item.value)}
                      name="select"
                      type="radio"
                      value={item.value}
                      onInput={(event) =>
                        this.handleSelect((event.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
                      }
                    />
                  </label>
                );
              }
            })}
          </div>
        </button>
        <div
          class={`overlay ${this.open ? 'open' : 'close'}`}
          role="button"
          onClick={() => this.toggleSelect('overlay')}
        ></div>
      </Host>
    );
  }
}
```

I have the following code and what happens is when I open the drop down and select an item - I get this in the logs

```
*/opening the drop down
select.entry.js:39 fired button
select.entry.js:39 toggleSelect: Open is now true

*/selecting an option notice the double click event
select.entry.js:37 fired button
select.entry.js:39 toggleSelect: Open is now false
select.entry.js:37 fired button
select.entry.js:39 toggleSelect: Open is now true
select.entry.js:44 handling select was: true now is **FALSE**
```

is there a way to prevent this from being called twice or is because I have a input radio tag inside the button tag

I would ideally not want to have to hard code a this.open =false on the handle select method

Answer (score -1):

This is a feature of React strict mode. React helps you detect side effects by running some functions twice. take a look: [Why is console.log logging twice in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62185425/why-is-console-log-logging-twice-in-react-js)